# Build a substrat node template on digitalocean problem

Tags: substrate-node-template

I try to cargo build the substrate node template on the server digital ocean. I have the exact same configuration between my own Ubuntu and Digitalocean droplet : Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /root/.rustup

```
installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
1.68.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
1.69.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)

active toolchain
----------------

1.69.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16).
```

When I cargo build the substrate node template, it works, whereas on digital ocean, I got this error :

```rs
Compiling sp-io v7.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.37#946507ba)
  error[E0557]: feature has been removed
    --> /root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/946507b/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:22:43
     |
  22 | #![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), feature(alloc_error_handler))]
     |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ feature has been removed
     |
     = note: now handled by panic handler.
```

As if my version of Rust was not correct. But it is the same between my computer and digitalocean. Does anyone has any ideas ? (rustc --version
rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16) in both case)

Answer (score 4):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Either use Substrate master to include the following fix: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13580
2. Or downgrade your rustc version to 1.68.0.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I just don't understand why with 1.69 it works on my local setup, and on digitalocean, which is the same Ubuntu, it does not work with 1.69 (with 1.68 it seams to works)...